# PyInstaller is not creating an .exe file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, exe, pyinstaller

I'm trying to create an executable file using PyInstaller with my script. For reference, I am using Windows 10 with Python 3.8.0 and PyInstaller version 3.5.

My script is called hello_world.py and it is saved in it's own folder.

```
print("Hello World!")
```

In command prompt, I navigate to the folder that hello_world.py is in and run:

```
pyinstaller hello_world.py
```

And this is the output:

```
46 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
46 INFO: Python: 3.8.0
46 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
62 INFO: wrote F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\hello_world.spec
78 INFO: UPX is not available.
78 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['F:\\Python\\Python Scripts\\Pyinstaller\\Py installer test',
 'F:\\Python\\Python Scripts\\Pyinstaller\\Py installer test']
78 INFO: checking Analysis
78 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
78 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
93 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
93 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3592 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
3592 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe
4014 INFO: Caching module hooks...
4014 INFO: Analyzing F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\hello_world.py
4045 INFO: Loading module hooks...
4045 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
4202 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
4202 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
4405 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
4420 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
4420 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py'
4420 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
5592 INFO: Looking for eggs
5592 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python38.dll
5592 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
5592 INFO: Warnings written to F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\build\hello_world\warn-hello_world.txt
5670 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\build\hello_world\xref-hello_world.html
5686 INFO: checking PYZ
5686 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
5686 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\build\hello_world\PYZ-00.pyz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 192, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\L&A\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 111, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 63, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 844, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 791, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "F:\Python\Python Scripts\Pyinstaller\Py installer test\hello_world.spec", line 18, in <module>
    pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 98, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 158, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 128, in assemble
    self.code_dict = {
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\api.py", line 129, in <dictcomp>
    key: strip_paths_in_code(code)
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 652, in strip_paths_in_code
    consts = tuple(
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 653, in <genexpr>
    strip_paths_in_code(const_co, new_filename)
  File "c:\users\l&a\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\utils.py", line 660, in strip_paths_in_code
    return code_func(co.co_argcount, co.co_kwonlyargcount, co.co_nlocals, co.co_stacksize,
TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

This creates folders called 'dist' and 'build' and a file called 'hello_world.spec' but the 'dist' folder is empty. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I search for

> TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)

[Did you read this?](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/4265)

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue in the past, can you please perform the follwing:
open Anaconda prompt or any other IDE per example spyder or Atom terminal, command line as admin and Navigate to the folder where the .py located and run the command as bellow:

In my example the file I want to compile it is getwindowsversion.py

this is will create just standalone .exe can be used,

`pyinstaller --onefile getwindowsversion.py`

if you want to create regular build,

`pyinstaller  getwindowsversion.py`

Comment: This only generate a file and not exe file. Why is it so>